# DJango: show different home page based on user.is_staff and request.user.is_authenticated()

Tags: python, django, django-views

Here's my simple home page view, which goes somewhere for staff, somehwere else for logged in users, and another for the rest:

```
def home(request):
    ipdb.set_trace()  ######### Break Point ###########

    if request.user.is_staff:
        redirect('quests:approvals')

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        redirect('quests:quests')

    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

However, the request is empty and has no info in it:

```
ipdb> request
<WSGIRequest: GET '/'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is just a single view within my main project app

I was previously using:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda user: not user.get_username(), login_url='myUrl', redirect_field_name=None)
def home(request):
...
```

Which works fine, except I couldn't figure out how to go somewhere else for staff users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you forgot a `return` there.

```
if request.user.is_staff:
    return redirect('quests:approvals')

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect('quests:quests')
```